# Is it possible to create a new query using LiveData inside the onChanged method of .observe?

Tags: java, android

The following code shows a simple database query, which gets a list of "inactive groups":

```
viewModel.getInactiveGroups().observe(this, new Observer<List<Group>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(List<Group> inactiveGroupList) {
        if (inactiveGroupList == null){
            int activeGroupNumber = ***I don't know what to do here***;
            if (activeGroupNumber != 0)
                buttonViewActiveGroups.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            //Rest of code to display list in recyclerview
        }
    }
});
```

When the list of inactive groups is empty, I need to check if there are any active groups to make a button visible

The problem is that I don't know how I should make that new query inside onChanged, is it necessary to do it with LiveData or what method can I use?

Basically this is my query I need: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Group WHERE isActive=1`

It is a database with Room, ViewModel and Repository, I do not attach more code because I do not consider it necessary, I only have doubts about the way in which a new query should be made within the onChanged method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing or understanding your data models, it seems like you can just create another query function in your Dao and a function in your ViewModel to call it and update the associated LiveData. So perhaps you have `ActiveGroups` as another LiveData field?

Comment: That's exactly what I did, I'm sorry for my question but I didn't have a clear understanding of how the repository works with the viewmodel and the activity that calls it. Thank you very much!